# Infer type of function argument by other function argument in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to declare function type like

```
type ReviewChangeHandler = 
    | ((newReview: Review, oldReview: null, options: {type: 'CREATE'}) => void)
    | ((newReview: Review, oldReview: Review, options: {type: 'EDIT'}) => void)
    | ((newReview: null, oldReview: Review, options: {type: 'DELETE') => void)
```

I want the type of `newReview` and `oldReview` argument to be inferred by the value of `options.type`, so I can write code like:

```
switch (options.type) {
    case 'CREATE':
        // `newReview` inferred to type `Review` and `oldReview` inferred to type `null`
    case 'EDIT':
        // `newReview` inferred to type `Review` and `oldReview` inferred to type `Review`
    case 'DELETE:
        // `newReview` inferred to type `null` and `oldReview` inferred to type `Review`
```

How can I achieve such behavior?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using function overloads rather than a union type here.

Comment: @kaya3 Can you explain more about how to use function overload in this case? I've read typescript documentation about function overloads but I can't apply it to my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bunch going on here.  First of all, I'm going to give `Review` a dummy definition so we can work with it:

```
interface Review {
  name: string;
}
```

---

Then, your union type of functions `ReviewChangeHandler` is unfortunately not going to be useful to you.   You presumably don't want your handler to be able to handle just *one* of those parameter lists, right?  You want it to handle *all* of those parameter lists. That is, you want a function of type `ReviewChangeHandler` to be the [*intersection*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) of the three call signatures, not the [*union*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of them:

```
type ReviewChangeHandler =
  & ((newReview: Review, oldReview: null, options: { type: 'CREATE' }) => void)
  & ((newReview: Review, oldReview: Review, options: { type: 'EDIT' }) => void)
  & ((newReview: null, oldReview: Review, options: { type: 'DELETE' }) => void)
```

---

TypeScript considers the intersection of functions to be the same as a function with multiple call signatures; that is, it's an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) function.  To write such a function you can declare multiple call signatures and then a single implementation signature that can accept any of the call signatures' inputs and return any of the call signatures' outputs.  Like this:

```
// three call signatures
function reviewChangeHandler(newReview: Review, oldReview: null, options: { type: "CREATE" }): void;
function reviewChangeHandler(newReview: Review, oldReview: Review, options: { type: "EDIT" }): void;
function reviewChangeHandler(newReview: null, oldReview: Review, options: { type: "DELETE" }): void;

// one implementation signature
function reviewChangeHandler(newReview: Review | null, oldReview: Review | null, options: { type: "CREATE" } | { type: "EDIT" } | { type: "DELETE" }) {
  // impl here
}
```

You can double check that the above function declarations matches the new `ReviewChangeHandler` intersection type by assigning it to a variable of that type:

```
const check: ReviewChangeHandler = reviewChangeHandler; // okay
```

---

Now you would like the compiler to be able to infer narrower types for `newReview` and `oldReview` based on the type of `options.type`.  Unfortunately this cannot really happen directly.  The compiler will not understand that separate union-typed variables are *correlated* this way (see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for discussion on the lack of support for correlated union types).  Instead you might want to package your separate union-typed variables into a single object of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) type.

A plausible first attempt at this would be to just put `newReview`, `oldReview`, and `options` as properties of an object:

```
  const reviewChangeAttempt = {
    newReview,
    oldReview,
    options
  };
```

But you'd need to `switch` on `reviewChangeAttempt.options.type`, a *nested* discriminant property.  And currently TypeScript does not recognize subproperties like this as valid discriminants.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758) for a feature request to support this.

If we want to gain the benefits of a discriminated union, we need to move the `options.type` subproperty up one level.  So this gives us the following type:

```
type ReviewChangeObj = {
  newReview: Review;
  oldReview: null;
  type: "CREATE";
} | {
  newReview: Review;
  oldReview: Review;
  type: "EDIT";
} | {
  newReview: null;
  oldReview: Review;
  type: "DELETE";
}
```

and a possible implementation like this:

```
  const reviewChange = {
    newReview,
    oldReview,
    type: options.type
  } as ReviewChangeObj;
```

Note that I have to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that `reviewChange` is a valid `ReviewChangeObj`. The compiler's lack of ability to follow the correlation between `newReview`, `oldReview`, and `options.type` means that any repackaging of these into a type the compiler *does* understand would cause the compiler to object without something like a type assertion.

Also note that this throws away anything else that you might have put into `options`; if you have other stuff in there you can hold onto it by making `ReviewChangeObj` elements have both an `options` and a `type` property.  But I digress.

---

After this, finally, you get the inference you want:

```
function reviewChangeHandler(newReview: Review, oldReview: null, options: { type: "CREATE" }): void;
function reviewChangeHandler(newReview: Review, oldReview: Review, options: { type: "EDIT" }): void;
function reviewChangeHandler(newReview: null, oldReview: Review, options: { type: "DELETE" }): void;
function reviewChangeHandler(newReview: Review | null, oldReview: Review | null, options: { type: "CREATE" } | { type: "EDIT" } | { type: "DELETE" }) {

  const reviewChange = {
    newReview,
    oldReview,
    type: options.type
  } as ReviewChangeObj;

  switch (reviewChange.type) {
    case 'CREATE': {
      console.log("CREATING NEW REVIEW: " + reviewChange.newReview.name);
      break;
    }
    case 'EDIT': {
      console.log("EDITING OLD REVIEW: " + reviewChange.oldReview.name + " AND NEW REVIEW: " + reviewChange.newReview.name);
      break;
    }
    case 'DELETE': {
      console.log("DELETING OLD REVIEW: " + reviewChange.oldReview.name);
    }
  }
}
```

You can see that inside the `case` statements the compiler understands exactly when `reviewChange.newReview` and `reviewChange.oldReview` are going to be `Review` and when they are going to be `null`.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQG7Agd2QbwChlkQ4BbCALmQGcwpQBzAbkIF9DCwBPABxTosuAMIALOCCYQAEpIAmAG2jIAvMWQAyZAAodIXEOw4aR3ABpkAe0XyzJ0gFdFiy1b5hgVkLRr5kvAI0AOQiqACiAIIAKuHByOwAlGoAfMgYVsDyiRraegY49qaYxm62RWglFtYeXj5+AfzUyMHhACIAktHxSanpmdm5uvqGVQ4gzq7W5WPFwjhutd6+BI1BLW3hADLhsT3JqmkZWTncTZXz4pLSAPIARgBWagQaBRX2bCQ2drNOLp9rZoAIjCUViQLY7GQAB8XiQ3r8Phpvu8xgDAsD2l0IRwYXDSKN5jQJv9kTMiRdjOimjQgZsduDIVwYI4QAhPN5kFAxlcpLIFMooCNCoixmUfhSSVN3Bz6qsMbTQTFwkCEokaMd5GwWWzZVyeRI+XIQEpoMLUfNxRbSjVZSt-ArkECsdFVUkNQNtaz2XV9ZdDdJjaahQjJZMraLLba6vbAbT6bsVWqPVkvbrfdz-dd+SbBebI8Y8VKIxT7EXw9Hlg1HSCIsq3XiHTSnS6G7Cm+s6dtE27kkQSAhlmA-cZedJImBIOQPM9+yQCSLLRovuTSsvKz4NOw2BpBz5h5nRwGUKp8fDCWv59MJZf546ZTGAHQYrfIOC0SmiY-3B4A2g4YAwAQMRdEPL9s2fJo+3XBB3xQUI6z2Px1wHZYbAgR9FCsJgdFrMEOgAOQAcWQAjwgAdTQcIADUOgo2lkAAahHcC+UfUNjHYigIESAErzubk4AAaz4hIYLgloXWCZCr1Qnx0Mw7DcJdQiSJuLY2io2j6KdJiWJwMcMJRMYuMoPTVUiAjNLIyiIm08iGOYsCDOPdiL1wUyeNEkgBIgYTRM4K9YNoeCEyQs95z3WgFKwnCuwZVTkHUzS7LohzdKcg0IOM+ZPN49dArEzhCCi4dgIgBAhLmI9syDQVnmcwy6ugFhkAAeja6whLgHggA)

Comment: Is it possible to use intersection for function types generics? Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65280785/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-typescript-function-which-works-on-both-numbers-and#answer-65281351