# How do I write the signature for a function where the argument types are dependent?

Tags: typescript, types

Is there a type-safe way of expressing this function?  In this example, I'm adding numbers, but the question is about the general pattern.

```js
type signature = 
    ((a: number, b: number) => number) & 
    ((a: bigint, b: bigint) => bigint);

// Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number | bigint' and 'number | bigint'.
const add : signature = (a, b) => a + b;
```

The two arguments can be two different types, but should never be both at the same time.  Is there a way to write this function type so it works?

Comment: related, possibly near enough for a dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/q/59745527 I haven't found a good way

Comment: That's unfortunate.  This *might* be different as no type-guard is involved.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65280785/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-typescript-function-which-works-on-both-numbers-and#answer-65281351)

Answer (score 2):

you can define all method types and then define a method to handle all defined types.

```js
function add(a: {option1:string}, b: number): number
function add(a: number, options: { option2: number }): number
function add(a: string, b: string, options: { options3: boolean }): number
function add(
    a: string | number|{option1:string},
    b: string | number | { option2: number }, 
    c: { options3: boolean } = {options3: false}
) {
    // todo
    return 0;
}

add({option1:'a1'},2)
add(1,{option2:2})
add('a','b',{options3:false})
```

```js
function add(a: number, b: number): number
function add(a: bigint, b: bigint): bigint
function add(a: any, b: any): number | bigint {
    return a + b;
}
```

or use generic types

```js
function add<T extends (string|number|bigint)>(a: T, b: T): T {
    return a as any + b;
}
add('a','b');
add(1,2);
add(1,'b'); // error
```